# How can I tell whether a zend_hash_key is an integer or a string?

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I am trying to apply a C function to each element in a `HashTable` with `zend_hash_apply_with_arguments`. To do this, my C function needs to have a signature that matches `apply_func_args_t`. The final argument needs to be a `zend_hash_key`, which is a struct that contains both an integer and a string. How can I tell which of those fields I should check to get the key?

Comment: This code snippet might help `if (zend_hash_get_current_key_ex(ht, &key, &klen, &index, 0, &position) == HASH_KEY_IS_STRING) {
 /* the key is a string, key and klen will be set */
} else {
 /* we assume the key to be long, index will be set */
}` reference - http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.tables.php

Comment: I specifically asked about using `zend_hash_apply_with_arguments`. When I use that function, the function that sees the `zend_hash_key` doesn't see the `HashTable`, and that doesn't work for checking a specific key.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Zend, but I've been digging through the sources (PHP 5.5.14) a bit. I found the following function in [**zend_hash.c**](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=Zend/zend_hash.c;h=d7188ea564efae819910c3319aa50b080b691341;hb=f444b33ee87d3745c3cea948549ec9ed07c8c9c4) which may or may not help you:

```c
ZEND_API int zend_hash_get_current_key_type_ex(HashTable *ht, HashPosition *pos)
{
  Bucket *p;
  /* ... */

      if (p->nKeyLength) {
        return HASH_KEY_IS_STRING;
      } else {
        return HASH_KEY_IS_LONG;
      }

  /* ... */
```

And in `zend_hash_apply_with_arguments()`, you'll find that `hash_key.nKeyLength` is set to `Bucket->nKeyLength`:

```c
ZEND_API void zend_hash_apply_with_arguments(/* ... */)
{
  Bucket *p;
  /* ... */
  Zend_hash_key hash_key;
  /* ... */

      hash_key.nKeyLength = p->nKeyLength;

  /* ... */

}
```

So, presumably, you can tell the types apart by inspecting `zend_hash.nKeyLength`. Are you *supposed* to do that outside of the Zend internals? I have no idea.

Comment: If the field has the information I need, I don't care if I'm not "supposed" to access it. Nothing in Zend is documented anyway. I just assumed that `nKeyLength` was the length of the key if it's a string.

Comment: This is correct, you can either check that nKeyLength is non-zero or arKey is non-null.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP7, the `zend_hash_key` struct has changed to:

```
typedef struct _zend_hash_key {
    zend_ulong h; // numeric key
    zend_string *key; // string key
} zend_hash_key;
```

you can see `Zend/zend_hash.c` in PHP sources and search the following:

```
if (p->key) {  // p is a Bucket and assign to the zend_hash_key struct
    return HASH_KEY_IS_STRING;
} else {
    return HASH_KEY_IS_LONG;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

to determine if a variable is a string or a number in php
try something like this

```
<?php
  $a = "123456";
  if (gettype($a)=="string" ){ echo $a," is a string<br>";}
  $a = 123456;
  if (gettype($a)=="integer" ){ echo $a," is an integer<br>";}
?>
```

Comment: I think you've misread the question.... this is asking about how to tell whether a hash key is a long or a string from within the actual PHP core code, not from within a PHP script

Comment: The C language hasnt a standard function for it.
In C++ it would be :
   #include <typeinfo>
   // put cout on a new line
   cout << typeid(variable).name() << endl;

Comment: This question, as I already stated, is about a struct that contains both a string and a long field. If you had read the question, you would see that I was asking how to determine which to look at.

Comment: sorry wasnt sure if your data was from php where you could have checked it before you pasted it to C